# An electronic book is made up of 500 pages there are 16 lines of 2400 bits lines of each page. computer space it will ocuppy on a computer in GB

Tags: algorithms

An electronic book is made up of 500 pages and there are 16 lines of 2400 bits lines of each page. compute the space it will ocuppy on a computer in GB

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this question is the most basic kind of a homework exercise. No idea is needed except the definitions and arithmetic of primary school.

Answer (score 0):

I mean if this is all the information you have then it's just $$\frac{500*16*2400 bits}{(1024^3)*8} ≈ 0.002235 GB = 2.28 MB $$